# "\r" is leaving characters from previous line

Tags: python, python-2.7, carriage-return

Example:

```
sys.stdout.write("\raaaa")
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.write("\rbb")
sys.stdout.flush()
# output: bbaa
```

so `\r` is returning to the begining of the line overwriting **only** characters within the new string range, is there any solution to this problem without using spaces to overwrite the rest characters ?

ANSI escape sequences doesn't do the trick neither.

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. If you want a more powerful console format, look into the `curses` module.

Comment: you can use `curses` as @TigerhawkT3 suggests but `curses` probaly use `\r` and spaces to do it :)

Comment: "ANSI escape sequences doesn't do the trick neither." Not even `clr_eol`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ANSI escape sequences doesn't do the trick SINCE i'd like it to work on windows console too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys

_lastlen = 0
def overwrite(s):
    global _lastlen
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + s + " "*(_lastlen - len(s)))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    _lastlen = len(s)

overwrite("aaaa")
overwrite("bb")
```